# Why there's no html attributes suggestion at my vs code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

Why there is no suggestion in my vs code ? when i'm about typing "onClick, href, src, etc" it is not showing the suggestion but in my older code or download from github it's show up. i already try reinstall vscode, reset user setting and still the same.

[image: example]
[image: example]

here is some setting and i already install some extension but seems not work

[image: here is my setting.json]

[image: and file assosiation]

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have to add .jsx as a extension :"html"

Comment: no it's not work